# How to convert JSON to CSV and then save to computer as CSV file

Tags: node.js, json, csv, json2csv

I'm currently trying to pull json data from and API, convert it to csv using the json2csv node.js module, and then save the data as a csv file on my laptop. However, when I run the script, nothing happens.

The json data is then formatted similar to the below data variable:

```
const apiDataPull = postDataRequest()
   .then(data => {
      data = [
         {
            'day': '*date*',
            'revenue': '*revenue value*'
         }
      ]
```

And this is to convert the data to csv and download it, which is where the problem seems to be arising:

```
apiDataPull.then(data => {

   json2csv({
      data: data,
      fields: ['day', 'revenue', 'totalImpressions', 'eCPM']
   },
   function(err, csv) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      fs.writeFile('pubmaticData.csv', csv, function(err){
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log('File Saved!')
      });
   });

});
```

There is data being pulled from the API, but it's not being saved. I'm not even sure if it's been converted to csv properly or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not starting the promises, and it looks like you are not using the json2csv correctly.

Take a look at this example:

```js
let json2csv = require("json2csv");
let fs = require("fs");

apiDataPull = Promise.resolve([
    {
        'day': '*date*',
        'revenue': '*revenue value*'
    }]).then(data => {
    return json2csv.parseAsync(data, {fields: ['day', 'revenue', 'totalImpressions', 'eCPM']})
}).then(csv => {
    fs.writeFile('pubmaticData.csv', csv, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('File Saved!')
    });
});
```

The saved file is:

```
"day","revenue","totalImpressions","eCPM"
"*date*","*revenue value*",,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this npm package - csv-stringify. 
https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-stringify

```
//Load HTTP module
const http = require("http");
var stringify = require('csv-stringify');
const fs = require('fs');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
//Create HTTP server and listen on port 3000 for requests
const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {        
stringify(jsonObject, {header:true}, function(err, output) {
        fs.writeFile('formatted_json.csv', output, 'utf8', function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Some error occured - file either not saved or corrupted file saved.');
            } else {
                console.log('It\'s saved!');
            }
        });
    });

});

//listen for request on port 3000, and as a callback function have the port listened on logged
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

This should help you. Create this file - name it index.js 
Make sure you have node & npm installed, and run in the same directory

```
npm install
npm install csv-stringify
node index.js
```

go to your browser open localhost:3000 and you will see formatted_json.csv created in the same directory where index.js is located. Hope this helps!